# create new file from text files in directory and insert text

Tags: linux

In the below I am trying to use all the `.txt` filenames in `file` to insert into `tmp` then insert `100` next to each, followed by each `$1` value up to the `.`. The tried does execute, but creates `tmp` files which I would like to avoid. Also, I am not sure how to insert the third column correctly. Thank you :).

**file** directory with files in it, wont always be 4

```
111_00.xxx.yy.xx.yy.txt
111_00.xxx.yy.xx.yy.xls
222_00.xxx.yy.xx.yy.txt
333_00.xxx.yy.xx.yy.txt
```

**desired**

```
111_00.xxx.yy.xx.yy.txt 100 111_00
222_00.xxx.yy.xx.yy.txt 100 222_00
333_00.xxx.yy.xx.yy.txt 100 333_00
```

**Tried**

```
touch tmp
ls *.txt | for i in 250; do awk -v a=$i '{print $1,a}' tmp; echo "" ; done >  tmp2
```

Comment: Don't parse `ls` output. Use `find(1)`.

Comment: No need `find` nor `ls`, but `glob`: `for i in *.txt; do`

Comment: Read up on `read`; try `help read`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `100` is a fixed value you can try the following

```
grep 'txt$' file.txt | awk -v value="100" '{split($0,a,"."); print $1,value,a[1]}' > result.txt
```

first you get the lines you need with `grep` and then `awk` takes care of the rest

After the edit, if the filenames are not in a file but in a folder you can do the following:

```
printf '%s\n' *.txt | awk -v value="100" '{split($0,a,"."); print $1,value,a[1]}' > result.txt
```

Comment: Thank you all :)

Comment: We are here to help @justaguy ;)